# Matching variables not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, return, return-value

The concept is simliar to a slider. [Here is the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mariahw1190/3yn8u3hh/1/)

Each section is set to:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

until assigned the "anim-in" class. The issue is with var $currSection and $nextSection that need the var $rightCounter to correctly evaluate.

```
var $currSection = $rightCounter;
var $nextSection = $rightCounter + 1;
```

$rightCounter is updated in the counter function:

```
    function counter (event){

    var $counterSelect = $(this).attr('id'); 

     if ( $counterSelect == "right") {

        if ( $rightCounter >= 0 && $rightCounter <= 4){
            $rightCounter += 1;
            console.log($rightCounter);

            if ($leftCounter <= 0) {
                $leftCounter = 0;
                console.log($leftCounter);
            }

            else {
                $leftCounter -= 1;
                console.log($leftCounter);
            }

        }

    }

    else {

        if ($leftCounter >= 0 && $leftCounter <= 4){

            $leftCounter += 1;
            console.log($leftCounter);

            if ($rightCounter <= 0) {
                $rightCounter = 0;
                console.log($rightCounter);
            }

            else {
                $rightCounter -= 1;
                console.log($rightCounter);
            }

        }

    }

    animOut();
    return $rightCounter;

};
```

The animOut function uses $currSection and $nextSection to redistribute classes, but they are not updating with the $rightCounter?

**Note: the console logs are there to show what the vars are evaluating to**

Comment: are you trying to create a slider?

Comment: @madalinivascu it has the same concept as a content slider

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because it doesn't include jQuery.

Comment: you have plenty of wheels out there don't invent another one :)

Comment: @madalinivascu I am trying to build my portfolio so I want to use primarily my own script